# Parsing a list of tokens in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, character, token

GOAL: I have a list of tokens. Whenever there is a section of tokens surrounded by brackets, such as {t1,t2,etc.}, I need to make that into a new sublist. An example is provided below of my desired result.

---

parse:['(facto)', 'dup', 'length', '/n', 'exch', 'def', '/fact', '{', '0', 'dict', 'begin', '/n', 'exch', 'def', 'n', '2', 'lt', '{', '1', '}', '{', 'n', '1', 'sub', 'fact', 'n', 'mul', '}', 'ifelse', 'end', '}', 'def', 'n', 'fact', 'stack'])

returns: 
 ['(facto)', 'dup', 'length', '/n', 'exch', 'def', '/fact', [0, 'dict', 'begin', '/n', 'exch', 'def', 'n', 2, 'lt', [1], ['n', 1, 'sub', 'fact', 'n', 'mul'], 'ifelse', 'end'], 'def', 'n', 'fact', 'stack']

---

Here is my code so far:

```
def parse1(L):
    newL = []
    for x in L:
        if x == '}':
            return newL
        elif x == '{': 
            newL.append(parse1(L[1:]))
        else:
            newL.append(x)
    return newL
```

It works to the extent that whenever a { occurs, I reclusively pass the rest of the list into the function again, with a base case being when } occurs. This is working okay, but once it exits the recursion and creates a sublist, the element "x" it's iterating through has not gone past this section. So for example, if our list is: ['{', '1', '}'], the result should simply be [[1]]. However, what is happening is it's returning [[1],'1'], because once it creates the sublist (which seems to be working fine) the next element "x" the loop is going through is actually an element of that sublist, it's the element right after the '{', and according to my code, it's then appended to the list.

I feel like this is a really easy fix, I have spent very long trying to figure it out though. I understand the issues, as I have explained, but cannot for the life of me figure out how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It isn't an easy fix; you are conflating processing a sub-list with processing the rest of a list.

Comment: I was considering trying to re-do it without using the built in for loop iterator, and trying to manually iterate through the list like L[0], L[1], etc, then try to find a way to change the index after I have processed a sublist.

I'm just pretty exhausted of options at this point, I've spent a while on this.

Comment: Your expected output seems to expect strings of integers to be converted into integers, yet your code does not even attempt to do this.

Comment: Changing an index, if you are using a while loop, is as simple as assigning an integer.

Comment: @ScottHunter yeah I am running into some issues with the integer thing as well. But for now I'm just trying to get the list to form properly before worry about formatting. I tried some a check to determine is x.isdigit, and if it was true, I tried newL.append(int(x)), but this didn't seem to work. I'm still working on that issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is modeled on your attempt at a solution (and also handles the integers):

```
# This assumes brackets are properly balanced
def parse1(L):
    newL = []
    i = 0
    while i<len(L):
        x = L[i]
        if x == '}':
            # Return the parsed list & the unparsed portion of the original list
            print(newL, L[i:])
            return newL, L[i+1:]
        elif x == '{': 
            # Split rest of L into parsed & unparsed portions
            parsed, unparsed = parse1(L[i+1:])
            # Insert parsed portion into current list
            newL.append(parsed)
            # Reset i & L for unparsed portion
            i, L = 0, unparsed
        else:
            # Convert x to an integer if possible
            try:
                x = int(x)
            except:
                pass
            newL.append(x)
            i += 1
    return newL
```